# Do i need to configure VS2012 to handle debugging with MVC and js function calls?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

In MVC there are alot of js function calls does through MVC ajax forms but the calls to js function from a onSuccess property of Ajax.BeginForm() cannot be captured in my VS2012 setup. How do i properly configure VS 2012 to debug calls to C# methods or razor or js function calls?

If this is not possible with VS 2012 what are tools that developers use and how to use them?

Answer (score 0):

You could place the resulting function in a .js file, which gets debug instrumentation added during compilation. In the normal .cshtml files, only the server side code can be stepped through.